# Modify SharePoint 2010 view

Tags: listview, sharepoint-2010

I've a document library and inside folder year
2010
2009
...

My customer would like a view to show all the items without folder.

For information, i'm in sandbox solution so my actions are reduce

Comment: Simply when you create a view, you have a tab "Folders" and select "Show all items without folders"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution si in the comment: 
Simply when you create a view, you have a tab "Folders" and select "Show all items without folders"